# How to combine the results of two DTOs in C# into one list of one type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, dto

I have a C# web app that is currently pulling data from two databases. One of the databases has a table called resources that contains employee details and the other contains a view to details collected in a company web app.

I need to create a list of each 'active' employee that also lists their web app history.

I want to return a List of type ResourceDTO with the results of the WebAppDTO in another list per user.

Ideally I will be able to manipulate this in Angular, Create a table listing employee names and in the next column "tally" up how many times they have participated. Each of the tally's will be a link that then uses the webappID to display the details for that employee.

```
C# Question for Satckoverflow

//Web Api

public List<ResourceDTO> GetWebAppLeaders()
        {
            List<ResourceDTO> webappLeaders = new List<ResourceDTO>();

            //Linq to get a list of employees that take part of Web App
            var people = from x in _staffCtx.Resources
                         where (x.Active.HasValue && x.Active.Value && x.ManagerID.HasValue && x.FirstName.Length > 0)
                         select new ResourceDTO()
                         {
                             FirstName = x.FirstName,
                             LastName = x.LastName,
                             ResourceID = x.ResourceID,
                         };

            webappLeaders = people.ToList();

            //currently loops through each member of staff in list above and grabs their web app history.
            foreach (var person in people)
            {
                int personID = person.ResourceID;

                var webappHistory = from u in _webappCtx.CompanyWebAppViews
                                    where (u.PupilID == personID || u.TeacherID == personID)
                                    select new WebAppDTO()
                                    {
                                        webappDate = u.webappDate.ToString(),
                                        webappID = u.ID,
                                    };
                webappHistory.ToList();
            }

            //webappLeaders.ToList();

            // successfully returns list of Employees as filtered out by where clause.
            return webappLeaders;

        }

'//ResourceDTO.cs

 public class ResourceDTO
    {
        public int ResourceID { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string ExtensionNumber { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string MobileSpeedDial { get; set; }
        public string IMAddress { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerID { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentType { get; set; }

        // Other field you may need

        //web app specific
        public List<WWebAppDTO> webappPupil { get; set; }

        public List<WebAppsDTO> webappTeacher { get; set; }

    }

//WebAppDTO.cs

    public class WebAppDTO
    {
        public int webappID { get; set; }
        public string pupilName { get; set; }
        public string teacherName { get; set; }

        public string webappDate { get; set; }

        public string pupilLearnt { get; set; }

        public string pupilComments { get; set; }

        public string teacherComments { get; set; }

    }
```

Apologies in advance if I have miss understood some vital concepts, C# MVC is new to me.

I would greatly appreciate some example code.

Thanks.

Comment: can you do a Join using Linq.. or could you not make one of the Classes a List<T> inside the other as a member..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes to the code resolved the issue for me.

```
//WebApi

public List<ResourceDTO> GetWebAppLeaders()
    {
        List<ResourceDTO> webappLeaders = new List<ResourceDTO>();

        //Linq to get a list of employees that take part of WebApp
        var people = from x in _staffCtx.Resources
                     where (x.Active.HasValue && x.Active.Value && x.ManagerID.HasValue && x.FirstName.Length > 0)
                     select new ResourceDTO()
                     {
                         FirstName = x.FirstName,
                         LastName = x.LastName,
                         ResourceID = x.ResourceID,
                     };

        webappLeaders = people.ToList();


        foreach (var person in webappLeaders)
        {
            int personID = person.ResourceID;

            person.webappPupil = from u in _webappCtx.CompanyWebAppViews
                                 where (u.PupilID == personID)
                                 select new WebappDTO()
                                 {
                                     webappID = u.ID,
                                 };
            person.webappPupil.ToList();

            person.webappTeacher = from u in _webappCtx.CompanyWebAppViews
                                   where (u.TeacherID == personID)
                                   select new WebappDTO()
                                   {
                                       webappID = u.ID,
                                   };
            person.webappTeacher.ToList();
        }


        return webappLeaders.ToList();

    }


//ResourceDTO
    public class ResourceDTO
{
    public int ResourceID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string ExtensionNumber { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string MobileSpeedDial { get; set; }
    public string IMAddress { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentType { get; set; }

    //WebApp specific
    public IQueryable<WebAppDTO> webappPupil { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<WebAppDTO> webappTeacher { get; set; }

}


//WebAppDTO

public class WebAppDTO
{
    public int webappID { get; set; }
    public string pupilName { get; set; }
    public string teacherName { get; set; }

    public string webappDate { get; set; }

    public string pupilLearnt { get; set; }

    public string pupilComments { get; set; }

    public string teacherComments { get; set; }

    public List<WebAppDTO> WebApp { get; set; }

}
```

Extending Stephen Vakil's answer, the for each loop complained about IQeuryable type conversion to List type. To resolve this two methods of type IQueryable where created in the ResourceDTO, to then be able to convert the result to list a method of tpye List was created in WebAppDTO, the final step involved taking the assignment webappLeaders = people.ToList() and feeding this into the foreach loop. The results now return a list of employees with further lists of their web app history.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but as far as I can tell you just need to initialize the two lists by querying in your for loop?

```
foreach (var person in people)
{
   int personID = person.ResourceID;   
   person.webappPupil = from u in _webappCtx.CompanyWebAppViews
                        where (u.PupilID == personID)
                        select new WebAppDTO()
                        {
                           webappDate = u.webappDate.ToString(),
                           webappID = u.ID,
                        }.ToList();
   person.webappTeacher = from u in _webappCtx.CompanyWebAppViews
                        where (u.TeacherID == personID)
                        select new WebAppDTO()
                        {
                           webappDate = u.webappDate.ToString(),
                           webappID = u.ID,
                        }.ToList();   
}
```